# Can only either receive or send via TCP

Tags: sockets, powershell, tcp

I'm having trouble writing a PowerShell script that can both send and receive data via a TCP connection. It only seems to let me do one or the other.

Below is what I have so far. I want to listen and wait for a connection, then once established, receive a string containing an IP address, do some fancy lookup to see what user is logged into that machine, then send back the username. If I only send data, it works. If I only receive data, it works. If I try to do both, only the receive works. What am I doing wrong?

```
$port = 1234

do {
  $user = ""

  $endpoint = new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([system.net.ipaddress]::any, $port)
  $listener = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
  $listener.start()

  $client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient() # will block here until connection
  $stream = $client.GetStream();

  $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $stream
  $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $stream

  $add = $reader.ReadLine()
  #$reader.close()

  write-host "Request from " $add

  if($add) {
    $user = & wmic /Node:$add ComputerSystem Get UserName
    write-host "User returned is " $user[2]
  }

  if($user[2] -eq "ERROR:") {
    $user[2] = "ErrNoUserW"
  } elseif(!$user[2]) {
    $user[2] = "ErrServerW"
  }

  $writer.Write($user[2])

  #$writer.close()
  $stream.close()
  $client.close()
  $listener.stop()
} while(1)
```

Comment: Could you post client side script to?

Comment: Right now I'm using Ncat (from the Nmap suite) for testing. So if you do a "/path/to/ncat  ip_address  port_number", then just type in an IP and press enter, it'll respond with the username (or, that's the idea anyway. Client side never sees the response).

Comment: Try to `$writer.Flush()`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. That was it!

Comment: As a side note, don't use `wmic` in a PowerShell script. Use `Get-WmiObject` instead: `$user = (Get-WmiObject -Computer $add -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the stream could only be read or write at any given time. Have you tried closing the stream then re-opening it?